# Классификация ip адресов

Tags: сеть, ip

Что такое адрес произвольной рассылки (anycast)? Для чего он нужен?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Any - любой, cast - бросать

Anycast - технология маршрутизации, предоставляет отправку пакета "первому попавшемуся" в anycast группе. Т.е. кто первый получил пакет - его и обрабатывает. Остальные участники Anycast группы этого пакета уже не увидят.

Если простым языком, то один и тот же IP-адрес назначается нескольким серверам, расположенным в разных местах и когда делается запрос по адресу - выбирается ближайший (чем меньше точек прохода пакета, тот ближе)

Более подробно в [статье с Habrahabr:](https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/187802/)

> Смысл метода Anycast заключается в анонсировании одинакового префикса
>   IP-адресов одновременно из нескольких точек сети через протокол BGP. В
>   результате данные передаются по наиболее короткому маршруту — на
>   ближайший узел, которому присвоен анонсированный IP-адрес. При этом
>   понятие «короткий маршрут» в данном случае трактуется не в
>   географическом, а в топологическом смысле.